# Wortstellung mit "zugegeben"

Tags: adverb, word-order

[Dem Wörterbuch](http://dictionary.reverso.net/german-english/zugegeben) zufolge kann man sagen

> (a) Zugegeben, das stimmt.

Das ist im Gegensatz zu der typischen Satzstellung

> (b) Zugegeben stimmt das.

Ist (b) auch ein korrekter Satz? Und was ist mit **zugegeben** besonders, womit man (a) ausdrücken kann?

Comment: Was genau meinst du mit "besonders" in diesem Zusammenhang?

Comment: @Gerhard Dass man zum Beispiel "Wahrscheinlich, das stimmt" nicht sagen würde.

Comment: Hm, ich könnte mir durchaus Fälle vorstellen,  wo man das sagen könnte: "Glaubst du nicht, dass er lieber Kuchen hätte? - Wahrscheinlich, das stimmt." (Im Sinne von "da hast du recht"). Aber zugegeben (sic!), das Beispiel ist ein bisschen konstruiert und vermutlich eher Umgangssprache.

Comment: @Gerhard Würdest du nicht auch meinen, dass man eher sagt "Wahrscheinlich stimmt das"?

Comment: In dem Fall das jemand etwas behauptet und du feststellst das er/sie recht hat, bleibt dir eigentlich nur "Zugegeben, das stimmt." Der zweite Satz ist aber auch gar nicht so falsch, wie es einem auf den ersten Moment vorkommt, und zugegeben stimmt das sogar wirklich. (Wobei die Verwendung des Adverbs zugegebenermaßen 'besser' wäre.)

Comment: @Em1: ich meinte eher im Sinne "Wahrscheinlich <Denkpause>, das stimmt". Wie gesagt, ein wenig konstruiert...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Zugegeben* kann ein Adverb sein (wie schon hier gesagt wurde und auch zu der Übersetzung von *admittedly*, vgl. [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/admittedly.html), passt), und in diesem Sinne heißt

> (b) Zugegeben stimmt das.

so viel wie

> Admittedly this is correct.

Allerdings ist diese Bedeutung für mein Sprachgefühl äußerst selten, und *zugegebenermaßen*, *zugegebenerweise* o. ä. üblicher.

Die erste Variante

> (a) Zugegeben, das stimmt.

ist eine abkürzende Schreibweise (als Partizip, vgl. [hier](http://conjd.cactus2000.de/showverb.php?verb=zugeben)) für

> Ich gebe zu, das stimmt.

oder

> I admit, this is correct.

Eine ähnliche Abkürzung gibt es im Beamtendeutsch, wenn man sagt *(Antrag) abgewiesen*, statt *ich weise (den Antrag) ab*.

Auch *geschenkt* scheint mir so ähnlich zu sein, wie in einer Diskussion verwendet, wenn man dem Argument des Gegners zustimmt, aber es nicht für wesentlich hält:

> "Ich behaupte XY." – "Geschenkt. Aber …"

Das Besondere an zugegeben ist also vermutlich nur, dass das Adverb genauso aussieht wie die Abkürzung als Partizip, was bei den anderen Beispielen nicht der Fall ist.

Answer (score 7):

For b) you’d have to use the adverb:

> Zugegebenermaßen stimmt das.

Comment: Das stimmt, zugegebenermaßen. :)

Comment: Zugegebenermaßen, das stimmt. :P

Answer (score 2):

*Zugegeben* ist das Partizip Perfekt von *zugeben* und *zugegebenermaßen* ist eine Wortbildung aus *zugeben* und *Maß*, welches nicht Bezug nimmt auf eine boolesche Aussage (wahr/falsch), sondern vielmehr eine erweiterte Bewertungsskala für die Aussage annimmt, die eben an einem Maß gemessen werden muss.<sup>[1][2]</sup>

Bei Variante **(a)** wird *zugegeben* als Ausruf verwendet und erhält dadurch mehr Gewicht. In der Regel handelt es sich hierbei also um eine Reaktion auf eine Falschaussage, die man zuvor formulierte.

> Zugegeben, …
>
> Zugegebenermaßen, …
>
> Freilich, …
>
> Gewiss, …
>
> Sicher, …
>
> Ich gebe zu, …

All diese Ersetzungen bedeuten im Endeffekt das Gleiche und spätestens jetzt sollte klar werden, dass hier lediglich die Verwendung als Ausruf besonders ist und nicht die Wörter selbst. Wir können auch die Beispiele von lukas.coenig als Ausrufe verwenden:

> Geschenkt, …
>
> Abgewiesen, …

Variante **(b)** ist meiner Meinung nach auf jeden Fall grammatikalisch ein korrekter Satz jedoch ohne Ausruf. Das bedeutet, dass der Einsicht eines Fehlers keine besondere Bedeutung angemessen wird. Ich würde diese Art der Satzstellung und -bildung der Rhetorik zuordnen. Also wenn ich eine Aussage tätige, von der ich selbst bereits weiß, dass sie nicht ganz korrekt ist oder nur annähernd zutrifft, und im nächsten Satz (oder Nebensatz) zugleich einräumen will, dass ich mir darüber im Klaren bin.

#### Referenzen

1. [Wiktionary: „zugegeben“](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zugegeben)
2. [Wiktionary: „zugegebenermaßen“](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zugegebenerma%C3%9Fen)

Comment: Guter Hinweis mit dem Ausruf! (Obwohl ich das nicht automatisch in jedem Fall als Ausruf empfinde. Gerade bei "zugegeben" folgt oft ein "aber", und in dem Fall will man das Zugeben ja nicht betonen, sondern das Aber.)

Comment: Wenn das Aber betont werden soll fallen mir zwei Möglichkeiten ein. (1) *„Zugegeben, aber, das stimmt …“* (2) *„Aber, zugegeben stimmt das …“* Im ersten Fall liegt die Betonung auf beiden und zwei Aufrufe folgen einander und im Zweiten ausschließlich auf dem Aber, zudem handelt es sich zugleich um ein weiteres gutes Beispiel zur eigentlichen Frage hier. :)

Comment: Oder halt einfach: "_Zugegeben, das stimmt. Aber_ [ich bin trotzdem stur und bleibe bei meiner Meinung]" ;-) Und auch hier wäre die Betonung auf dem Aber. 
(Ich bin übrigens erstaunt, dass die Frage nicht mehr Resonanz zeigt, nachdem es sogar einen Bounty gibt...)

Comment: Die Aufteilung in zwei gesonderte Sätze funktioniert natürlich auch wunderbar und das Beispiel passt auch sehr gut. ;) Es ist immer abhängig davon was man genau aussagen will. Die Form ohne Ausruf sieht man jedoch nur sehr selten und wenn dann in Editorials, Meinungsbildern oder einfach Büchern. Deutsche Sprache, schwere Sprache, darum antworten wohl auch kaum Benutzer. Ich bin ja auch nur hobbymäßig hier unterwegs und die Frage weckte einfach mein Interesse (die Bounty war mir egal).